# How to dynamically define metrics in Prometheus (k8s)

Tags: go, kubernetes, prometheus

I am writing an exporter and am having trouble with metrics for my collector. From what I can tell, metrics in Prometheus need to be defined beforehand. Is there any way to define them dynamically at runtime instead? I won't know how many metrics I'll have or what metrics I'll need until the code is running. (For example, if k8s finds all volumes connected to the cluster, and I need EACH volume to get its own total_capacity/available_capacity metric).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would handle this by using dynamic label values rather than dynamic metric names. That said, you can call `prometheus.Register()` at runtime just fine, client_golang won't know the difference.

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd do that, I can't find much on the subject. From what I can tell, to define a metric I have to define it in my collector struct, populate it in the constructor with prometheus.NewDesc(), pass it to prometheus desc channel within Describe() and determine how it will be collected in Collect(). I can register a collector with prometheus.MustRegister() at any time, but how can I make changes to that collector's metrics?

Comment: To reiterate, you should be using labels, but you would just make new collectors as needed. Or just bin the whole of client_golang and write your own if you need something more dynamic, the serialization format isn't very hard :)

Comment: @TrevorJordy, no, you don't have call NewDesc in the constructor. Yes, you have to use a description in Describe and Collect, but how it gets there is entirely up to you. I agree that you should just be using labels, in which case you *do* know the descriptions in advance (there's no harm in sending a description in Describe and then not to use it in Collect).

Comment: @coderanger I'm looking into labels and trying to understand. Is the idea that I'd be able to have multiple copies of the total_volume_capacity metric, each just with different labels? for example: total_volume_capacity{name:"volume1"}, total_volume_capacity{name:"volume2"}

Comment: That's the idea, yes :)

Comment: On all this discussion here, for a newbie to Prometheus, it would certainly be nice if someone had an example implementation of dynamically generated metrics sent to prometheus, as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I have only used Python and Java Prometheus clients so far, but isn't it just a recommendation to define metrics beforehand? In Java I can create the metrics at run-time inside methods or wherever I want. I just have to make sure that the same metric is not created again or an exception will be thrown by the library.